Heidegger made analytic?
I would like to understand Heidegger a little more compactly, if possible.
One of his concepts is “dasein”, “being there”.
My understanding is that a key aspect of dasein is roughly “self-awareness”. I suppose it is a level of cognitive complexity in which an entity perceives or acknowledges its own existence. Something that is “there” exists interactively with a world.
Zuhandenheit, or, being “at hand”, appears to be objects as they are perceived by consciousness. Part of the idea is how consciousness, with intention or intentionality, can perceive a hammer as an element in its own consciousness. Thus, it seems the “thing” that a hammer is noumenally differs from the thing it becomes phenomenally, in a being’s mind.
Vorhandenheit or “presence” is something like the cognitive (or platonic) prototype of a thing, as an ontologically defined structure (I think).
I am wondering if this can be reformulated by exploring what differentiates “things” from “non-things”, if at all possible, and then by adding in further well-defined properties that a given “thing” may have. Of course, at some point, we would expect a “thing” to have inner experience and an inner representational system.
I suppose it would be interesting to understand how Heidegger problematizes the question of “Being” in the first place: what is the problem - what issues are raised, what questions need answering?

OP: "My understanding is that a key aspect of dasein is roughly “self-awareness”. I suppose it is a level of cognitive complexity in which an entity perceives or acknowledges its own existence."
This sounds rather like Descartes' cogito ergo sum where Descartes' cogito acknowledges its existence, but Heidegger reformulates this.

If the 'cogito sum' is to serve as the point of departure for the
existential analytic of Dasein, then it needs to be turned around, and
furthermore its content needs new ontologico-phenomenal confirmation.
The 'sum' is then asserted first, and indeed in the sense that "I am
in a world".
B&T
211

Heidegger starts with Dasein's being-in-the-world ...

The compound expression 'Being-in-the-world' indicates in the very way
we have coined it, that it stands for a unitary phenomenon. This
primary datum must be seen as a whole. B&T
53

... and Dasein, which is 'there', da, and must be 'in' something, ...

If, in the ontology of Dasein, we 'take our departure'
from a worldless "I" [such as Descartes' cogito] in order to provide this "I" with an Object and
an ontologically baseless relation to that Object, then we have
'presupposed' not too much, but too little. B&T
315-6

... either authentically (focused) or inauthentically (lost in activity).

Dasein is an entity which, in its very [existence], comports itself
understandingly towards [its existence]. In saying this, we are
calling attention to the formal concept of existence. Dasein exists.
Furthermore, Dasein is an entity which in each case I myself am.
Mineness belongs to any existent Dasein, and belongs to it as the
condition which makes authenticity and inauthenticity possible. In
each case Dasein exists in one or the other of these two modes
[authentic or inauthentic], or else it is modally undifferentiated.
... these are both ways in which Dasein's Being takes on a definite
character, and they must be seen and understood a priori as grounded
upon that state of Being which we have called "Being-in-the-world". B&T
53

The world in which Dasein finds itself is undifferentiated.  Heidegger first lays out the temporal basis for subjective understanding (memory of past, intentionality for future, awareness of present), and then the apprehension of environmental spaciality.

Only on the basis of its ecstatico-horizonal temporality is it possible for Dasein to break into space. The world is not
present-at-hand in space; yet only within a world does space let
itself be discovered. B&T 421

Objects found in space are referred to as present-at-hand (Vorhandenheit) but in terms of utilisation they become ready-to-hand (Zuhandenheit).

Equipment can genuinely show itself only in dealings cut to its own
measure (hammering with a hammer, for example); ... In dealings such
as this, where something is put to use, our concern subordinates
itself to the "in-order-to" which is constitutive for the equipment we
are employing at the time; the less we just stare at the hammer-Thing,
and the more we seize hold of it and use it, the more primordial does
our relationship to it become, and the more unveiledly is it
encountered as that which it is—as equipment. The hammering itself
uncovers the specific 'manipulability' ["Handlichkeit"] of the hammer.
The kind of Being which equipment possesses—in which it manifests
itself in its own right—we call "readiness-to-hand"
[Zuhandenheit]. B&T
69

Involvement with things in the world can lead to total absorption, a self-forgetting (Selbstverlorenheit). (In this way even the ego can be seen as an inauthentic construct.)  In contrast to being inauthentically lost in activity, the mode of authenticity is more focused and holistic thinking and being.
OP: "I suppose it would be interesting to understand how Heidegger problematizes the question of “Being” in the first place: what is the problem"?
In understanding and thinking there is a presumption of an understanding of being ...

That wherein Dasein already understands itself in this way is always
something with which it is primordially familiar. This familiarity
with the world does not necessarily require that the relations which
are con­stitutive for the world as world should be theoretically
transparent. However, the possibility of giving these relations an
explicit ontologico­-existential Interpretation, is grounded in this
familiarity with the world; and this familiarity, in turn, is
constitutive for Dasein, and goes to make up Dasein's understanding of
Being.
B&T 86

... but if we dig into what being actually means, in the first place it is indefinable, (note iv below, B&T 4

We cannot undertake to define being without falling into [an]
absurdity: for we cannot define a word without beginning with the word
it is, either expressed or understood. To define being therefore, it
is necessary to say it is, and thus to employ the word defined in
the definition. (Pascal, Of the Geometrical Spirit)

Nor can being be an entity, for if being is the foundation of entities it cannot itself be an entity.

It has been maintained secondly that the concept of 'Being' is
indefinable. This is deduced from its supreme universality,iv and
rightly so, if definitio fit per genus proximum et differentiam
specificam [if "definition is achieved through the proximate genus
and the specific difference" (no higher genus for being!)]. 'Being'
cannot indeed be conceived as an entity; enti non
additur aliqua natura: nor can it acquire such a character as to have
the term "entity" applied to it. "Being" cannot be derived from higher
concepts by definition, nor can it be presented through lower ones. B&T 4

The problem that talking about Being makes Being into something is discussed by Derrida.

"the expression Sein is not only an infinitive but a verbal
substantive ... It consolidates [being] and makes it into something.
... Should we abandon a grammatical form that is so threatening for
the right thinking of being, a thinking that is neither a concept nor
a thinking of a being? ... What would happen if giving up on the
grammatical form of the verbal substantive in philosophical discourse,
we had to limit ourselves to the other forms? ... In that case, one
would say: being? — I know nothing about it. I do not know what that
means, primarily because I’ve never come across it and no one will
ever come across it. The pre-comprehension Heidegger talks about at
the beginning of Sein und Zeit is in this case merely an
incomprehension. I understand what being means only when being comes
to determine something or is determined by something, when I say I
am, and you are, and he or it is, and so on." (Jacques Derrida,
Heidegger: The Question of Being & History, 1964, p. 51–52)

Heidegger circumscribes Being to draw out its modes, but these are all dependent on Dasein and world.

To put it formulaically: both our normal focus on beings and the
metaphysical inquiry into their Being obscures Being itself. We spend
our everyday lives dealing with various entities – alarm clocks, cars,
taxes, police officers – while a select few disengage from this
busyness to metaphysically investigate how these beings are, but none
of us attend to the fundamental fact that they are. We pay attention
to what is present and its manner of presenta­tion, but not to its
presence, to the utterly simple fact that we are open to it. ...
This covering over is quite natural; as Heidegger likes to trans­late
Heraclitus, Being loves to hide (An Introduction to Metaphysics 120-1). Being has to withdraw for
us to deal effectively with the particular beings in front of us.
Light only renders objects visible if it is invisible itself; seeing
the light would block our perceptions of the things that are lit, like
blocks of amber separating us from the object. Just as light reveals
by remaining concealed, so Being withdraws from explicit awareness to
let beings present themselves. (Lee Braver, Heidegger's Later
Writings p.121).


@local Heidegger thinks of ontology as the science of being. "... these ontological foundations can never be disclosed by subsequent hypotheses derived from empirical material, but that they are always 'there' already, even when that empirical material simply gets collected. If positive research fails to see these foundations and holds them to be self-evident, this by no means proves that they are not basic or that they are not problematic in a more radical sense than any thesis of positive science can ever be." B&T 50
